# how to read file in cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm a newbie to cucumber. I've the following scenario that I want to code in cucumber:

```
Feature: Withdraw Fixed Amount
The "Withdraw Cash" menu contains several fixed amounts to
speed up transactions for users.

Scenario Outline: Withdraw fixed amount
  Given I have <Balance> in my account
  When I choose to withdraw the fixed amount of <Withdrawal>
  Then I should receive <Received> cash
  And the balance of my account should be <Remaining>

Examples:
| Balance | Withdrawal | Received | Remaining |
| $500    | $50        | $50      | $450      |
| $500    | $100       | $100     | $400      |
```

I 'd like to read the data (Examples:)from a file like this:
$500;$50;;$50;$450
$500;$100;$100;$400

I'm not sure if I can read data from cucumber's feature file or in the step definitions. Could someone please shed some lights on this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**No** it's not possible to 'generate' scenarios in Cucumber.  Each row in your example table runs as an individual scenario, and Cucumber must know up-front which scenarios are to be run.

That said, there are 2 possibilities, I'd consider both to be quite unattractive:

- Write the entire scenario in code in a single step def e.g.:

  ```
  Scenario: Withdraw fixed amount
    Given withdrawing should work correctly

  #steps.rb
  Given /^withdrawing should work correctly$/ do
    # Read values from file
    # For each row in the file, do everything the scenario would do
  end
  ```

  This works but will have the serious drawback of revealing *nothing* about the behaviour of the system through the Gherkin feature.
- Code gen the feature file.  Use a templating language such as ERB to transform a feature file, inserting whatever example rows are necessary, as a task which occurs before running Cucumber.  Effective, but at the cost of a *LOT* of complexity.

In both situations you're removing the numbers from the feature file, which immediately negates its function as a central source of documentation, readers would have to refer back to the 'numbers' file in order to figure out the actual behaviour of the system.

Answer (score 0):

What you requested is overkill. Examples are here to help you identify possible cases in clear format, but not for mass data handling.

Each row in Examples should be meaningful otherwise you are wasting resources.

For example. With $100 balance, withdrawal of $20 should leave $80. But $20 may be a hardcoded number, so you need one more case to verify that, say withdrawing $30.

The ATM system may have a daily withdrawal limitation of $1000. So, if you ask for $1200, the system should only give you $1000. You need another row to test that.

Every case above is meaningful. And I don't think there are so much cases that you need a CSV file to handle it. Manual typing is good enough.